# Converting string to JSON Object Error Parsing Data

Tags: android, json, parsing

the code which i used its working perfectly on localhost but i tried to excute that on my web server not getting whats wrong in parsing its showing wrror while parsing from string to JSON object

My JSON Parser Code is

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        is, "utf-8"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    json = sb.toString();
    Log.d("converted result", json);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}

// try parse the string to a JSON object
try {
    jObj = new JSONObject("{" + json +"}");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}

// return JSON String
return jObj;
```

LogCat Information

```
01-29 11:45:53.556: D/Search keyword:(921): saint louis
01-29 11:45:57.288: D/converted result(921): 
connected{"products":[{"pid":"406355","name":"852610 SOUTHCOUNTYMALL"},{"pid":"406356","name":"852611 SOUTHCOUNTYMALL"},{"pid":"406357","name":"852612 SOUTHCOUNTYMALL"}],"success":1}

01-29 11:45:57.288: E/JSON Parser(921): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Expected ':' after connected at character 11 of {connected{"products":[{"pid":"406355","name":"852610 SOUTHCOUNTYMALL"},{"pid":"406356","name":"852611 SOUTHCOUNTYMALL"},{"pid":"406357","name":"852612 SOUTHCOUNTYMALL"}],"success":1}
01-29 11:45:57.288: E/JSON Parser(921): }
```

Comment: if you remove the connected word, what remains is a valid Json object

Comment: Where is the "connected" piece from the beginning of the string coming from. That's your invalid json...

Comment: @Pete i am new to JSON please help me how to remove connected

Comment: @Devender, it's coming from your stream, so it's somewhere before the code you've got posted, so I have no idea.

Comment: @Pete is that possible to Trim that in JSON parser

Comment: @Pete  thankx friend i used this  json = json.substring(9); worked

Comment: The correct solution is what SLaks recommends. Fix the incoming data. Don't try to code around it. That's kludgy and then, if the incoming data gets fixed, that would break your code. Always try to fix the source of the problem, don't try to work around it unless there's no other option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error clearly states, your JSON is not valid, because of the word `connected` in front of it.

You need to make your server stop sending that word.

Answer (score 1):

You have this JSON:

```
{connected{"products":[{"pid":"406355","name":"852610 SOUTHCOUNTYMALL"},{"pid":"406356","name":"852611 SOUTHCOUNTYMALL"},{"pid":"406357","name":"852612 SOUTHCOUNTYMALL"}],"success":1}
```

This is an invalid JSON format because you have the wrong expresion '{connected' in the beginning of the JSON. Maybe, you should get a JSON like this:

```
{"products":[{"pid":"406355","name":"852610 SOUTHCOUNTYMALL"},{"pid":"406356","name":"852611 SOUTHCOUNTYMALL"},{"pid":"406357","name":"852612 SOUTHCOUNTYMALL"}],"success":1}
```

or like this:

```
{"connected":[VALUE], "products":[{"pid":"406355","name":"852610 SOUTHCOUNTYMALL"},{"pid":"406356","name":"852611 SOUTHCOUNTYMALL"},{"pid":"406357","name":"852612 SOUTHCOUNTYMALL"}],"success":1}
```

Anyway, I recommend you to use the Gson library to build and get JSONs.

Comment: You also can use this web to validate your JSON's syntax: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: or like: `{"connected":{"products":[{"pid":"406355","name":"852610 SOUTHCOUNTYMALL"},{"pid":"406356","name":"852611 SOUTHCOUNTYMALL"},{"pid":"406357","name":"852612 SOUTHCOUNTYMALL"}],"success":1}}`